# Using ShinyStorePlus while having a fileInput

Tags: r, shiny

I want to use shinyStorePlus to save inputs after this app is refreshed. What I have found is that if the app contains a fileInput then shinyStorePlus stops working altogether. I tried to work around this by giving a list of the specific inputs I want to save in setupStorage, however, this does not seem to work either. Is there anyway I can save the inputs after the app is refreshed while also keeping my fileInput?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyStorePlus)


if(interactive()){
  ui<-shiny::fluidPage(

    initStore(),
    useShinyjs(),
    fileInput("file1", "Choose .xlsx File", accept = ".xlsx"),
    actionButton("refresh","refresh"),
    numericInput("Qv", "", 1400),
    
  )

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$refresh, {
      refresh()
    })
    
    appid <- "application01"
    
    setupStorage(
      appId = appid,
      inputs = list("Qv")
    )
  }

      shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

You can read more about shinyStorePlus here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyStorePlus/shinyStorePlus.pdf